# moment gives local time instead of configured timezone time in centos

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, centos, momentjs, centos6

In my application i am running below code and it is hosted on two different servers as development (centos) and production (ubuntu) but the result is different in both servers.

```
console.log('Time --->>>>' + moment().valueOf() +' / '+ new Date());
var customeTime = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').toString();
console.log('customeTime time----->'+customeTime);
```

For **centos**: Above code gives result in local time which is IST where as timezone in my server is set to EST. I don't know why!!!

For **ubuntu**: Above code gives correct result which is EST and timezone is also EST.

Settings for Centos:

```
$: ls -l /etc/localtime
/etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York

$: vi /etc/sysconfig/clock
ZONE="America/New_York"

$: date
Thu Jan 12 01:48:03 EST 2017
```

Comment: I gather this is a node.js, not a browser question

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes its a application code. I made it more descriptive now.